# Unir multiples PDF's con jasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, estoy tratando de unir varios PDF en un solo archivo pero solo me carga los archivos en un archivo ya existente. Yo quisiera que se me imprimiera en una nueva página web de mi aplicación.
He estado utilizando esta línea de código

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jp1, outStream); para un solo archivo.

como podría hacer para unir varios pdf? Agredecería mucho sus comentarios....

Asi tengo mi codigo hasta el momento

```
for (int i = 0; i < algo.length; i++) {


                results.put("EVALUATION_NUMBER", Integer.parseInt(algo[i]));

                LOG.info("All Generated PDF");
                jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, results, con);

                jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint);


                System.out.println(jasperPrintList.get(i));

                List<JRPrintPage> pages = jasperPrintList.get(i).getPages();

                  JasperPrint jp1 = new JasperPrint();

                    for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {

                        JRPrintPage object = pages.get(j);
                        jp1.addPage(object);

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde conozco, Jasper solo puede generar PDFs desde sus plantillas, no tiene funcionalidades de unir PDFs. Para unir PDFs, puedes utilizar una librería que trabaje con PDFs como [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). Aquí un ejemplo de cómo los puedes mezclar con esta librería, adaptado de [este sitio](http://burnignorance.com/java-web-development-tips/java-merging-multiple-pdfs-into-a-single-pdf-using-itext/):

```
public class ItextMerge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
        try {
            // PDFs a unir
            list.add(new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Temp/1.pdf")));
            list.add(new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Temp/2.pdf")));

            // PDF final
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Temp/result.pdf"));

            doMerge(list, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Mezclar múltiples archivos PDF en uno
     * 
     * @param list Lista de InputStream de los archivos PDF a unir
     * @param outputStream Stream de archivo de salida del PDF
     * que resulta de la unión de los streams de la lista de entrada
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void doMerge(List<InputStream> list, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {
        //crear un nuevo documento PDF
        Document document = new Document();
        //crear un escritor del PDF
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        //para cada PDF en la lista
        //leer su contenido por página e ir agregando
        //cada página en el PDF de la variable document
        for (InputStream in : list) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                //import the page from source pdf
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                //add the page to the destination pdf
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        //cerrar streams para liberar recursos
        //y cualquier bloqueo de archivo
        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```